# Play cookie path different than context path

Tags: cookies, nginx, playframework

I have a play application behind a reverse_proxy.
My play application has a prefix, /www (and I need it like that for questions out of the scope of this one), so in my reverse_proxy I rewrite everything coming to / into /www.

For this to work, I need to setup http.path=/www in the play config. So far, so good.

The problem is that by changing http.path, I'm also changing the Play session cookie path, and I don't want that, because my browser only sometimes sees /www in the URL, and I don't want to do hard HTTP redirects (30x).

As far as I've been able to read in the docs and other questions at SO, this is not possible, so posting hoping that it actually is, or there's some nginx/play combo trick that I can use to get it work as I want to avoiding the browser redirects.

Comment: Are you looking for http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cookie_path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're looking for [`proxy_cookie_path`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cookie_path).